# Firebase functions failing to deploy: Missing URI for HTTPS function in printTriggerUrls. This shouldn't happen

Tags: firebase, express

I have an express app (API only) that is working locally `cd functions && npm start` but for whatever reason fails to deploy.

running `firebase --debug deploy` or `firebase --debug deploy --only functions` yield the same result which I don't understand.

Seeking advice for how to fix this or even how to dig into these firebase logs to better determine the problem

```
[info] Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    server(us-central1)
[debug] [2021-12-29T02:27:03.977Z] Missing URI for HTTPS function in printTriggerUrls. This shouldn't happen
[info] i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. The solution was removing this line:

```js
logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
```

Example code:

```js
export const helloWorld = region(regionName).https.onRequest((_, response) => {
    // logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```